# ionic 2/3 checking if label text is being truncated or not to use it as condition

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic3

I have these labels and this button

```
...let item of items...
<ion-label *ngIf="item.textwrap" text-wrap>{{item.record_view}}
</ion-label>
<ion-label *ngIf="!(item.textwrap)" >{{item.record_view}}
</ion-label>
<button ion-button (click)="textWrap(item)" clear item-right >
    <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

The purpose of this code is to show all the text if the button is pressed.
This solution is not elegant at all and I don't like it at all, but after ages of searches I've got only to that.

I would better like to add the button only if label text is being actually truncated, something like:

```
<ion-label [ngStyle]="ITEM.WRAPTEXT" >{{item.record_view}}
</ion-label>
<button ion-button *ngIf="IS_LABEL_TRUNCATED" (click)="textWrap(item)" clear item-right >
    <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

using state variables in the .ts file like

```
textWrap(item){
  if(item.textwrap==""{
    item.textwrap = "text-wrap" //or true
  }else{
    item.textwrap = "" //or false
  }
}
```

Do you guys have any solution to achieve such a result?

thanks to everybody

Comment: added textWrap() function.. it just changes the state of textWrap. In the code I posted it actually switches between the first and the second ion-label.